# Did the First Order follow Poe to Jakku, or did they independently discover that the map fragment was there?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens* we see Poe talking to Lor San Tekka and receiving the map fragment, and then the First Order suddenly shows up. Is there anything in canon to indicate whether Poe was followed to Jakku, or did the First Order just happen to independently discover that clues to Luke's whereabouts might be on Jakku and also just happen show up at the same time as Poe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to *Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Storybook* the First Order found out about Poe's mission and went to take the map from him. It is unclear from this if they already knew that the map was there but it seems unlikely.

> The First Order had discovered Poe's mission. They had sent a platoon of stormtroopers to capture Poe and take the precious map. Already, they could hear the him of ships landing at the edge of the village.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Storybook*</sub>

Comment: Interesting. It seems that while they knew about the mission they must not have known that it was *Poe's* mission, since shortly later Ren says, "I had know idea we had the best pilot in the resistance on board." Regardless, this answers the question, at least as far as it seems it can be answered.

Comment: And this is why you don't just accept the first pretty answer that comes along....

Comment: @Valorum ha, fair enough. In that case maybe this and your answer that gives some more detail regarding the timeline and context can somehow be edited together to yield the comprehensive answer. I'm still (very) new here, so I'm not sure what that process would look like. I yield to you and OP on that one.

Comment: @airshanemode - Acceptance is entirely up to you, as is *unacceptance* if you think a better answer has come along. On a pure housekeeping note, I'd always suggest that questioners should wait at least a few hours (or even days) *even if they think an answer is absolutely impenetrable* as you never know what the next guy will come up with.

Comment: @Valorum I'll wait longer next time before accepting. That said, at least given my limited experience, ideally this answer and yours are merged since both provide useful information (though I think yours is more comprehensive and more completely answers the question). I'm not sure if the comments are the place discussing protocol, or if it should transition to "meta" or "chat", however those work. Either way, I'm in East Asia currently and it's super late here. If there's a way to merge or an appropriate place to discuss this further let me know and I'll follow up morning my time.

Comment: Looking at this and the answer from @Valorum they seem to contradict each other, as this says The First Order "discovered Poe's mission" whereas Valorum's answer implies that it's basically the other way around - The Resistance discovers what The First Order knows and simply beats them to Jakku. If we can find a way to reconcile these two conflicting narratives that would be great.

Comment: @airshanemode - I don't think they're mutually contradictory. They discovered his mission *independently*, like two people  'discovering' the same item at an auction.

Comment: You might also want to note that the very junior novels (first reader books and mini storybooks) often contain canon inaccuracies as the fallout of having to explain something very briefly to a less sophisticated audience.

Answer (score 7):

This was addressed in the canon novelette, [Star Wars: Before the Awakening - Poe.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Before_the_Awakening) In short, Leia had become aware that a Senator named Erudo Ro-Kiintor was in cahoots with the First Order and had been dealing in information in return for money and influence. She had Poe raid his vessel and seize some info that he'd uncovered about the location of Lor San Tekka, an archaeologist with a deep knowledge of the Jedi Order and who had been working with Luke on uncovering the location of the first Jedi temple.

It's worth noting that they're not after a *map* (per se). Both Leia and Kylo Ren/Snoke simply think that Lor will know exactly where Luke is.

> We obtained a lot of information from the computers aboard *Hevurion Grace*,” Leia said, looking at the chip. “A wealth of information. But there was something else, something that…others may have missed. A piece of a puzzle I’ve been working for…for a long time to solve.”
>   She set the data chip in Poe’s palm.
>   “I think the First Order is trying to solve it, too, Poe. We have to solve it first. We have to find him first.”
>   “Who?”
>   “His name is Lor San Tekka.”
>   “Lor San Tekka,” Poe repeated. “Why’s the First Order so desperate to find him?”
>   “They think he knows something. I’m hoping he does, too.” Leia took his hand and folded his fingers closed over the data chip. She met his eyes. “I’m hoping Lor San Tekka knows where to find my brother, Poe. And Luke Skywalker may be the only hope we have left.”

From the point that Poe returned to Leia with the info, he only had a few hours head start before the First Order also received the same information and headed off to Jakku to find Lor, hence why they arrived at Jakku almost simultaneously and both headed to the correct village.

Answer (score 0):

This is all explained in Star Wars Battlefront II. Kylo Ren gets the information out of Del.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could greatly improve this answer by editing it to include any relevant quotes, like those provided by the previous answers.